# Sigma locally finite basis in (R, usual metric)

Tags: general-topology

Can we write down a sigma locally finite basis of (R, usual metric)

General construction for metric spaces need axiom of choice and is just an exiatence proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mathscr{B}$ be the base consisting of the open intervals in $\Bbb R$ with rational endpoints. $\mathscr{B}$ is countable, so we can enumerate it as $\mathscr{B}=\{B_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$. For $n\in\Bbb N$ let $\mathscr{B}_n=\{B_n\}$. Then each $\mathscr{B}_n$ is trivially locally finite, so $\mathscr{B}$ is $\sigma$-locally finite.

This argument of course works equally well in any second countable space: a countable base is automatically $\sigma$-locally finite, even $\sigma$-locally discrete.

Comment: Theorem (Hahn-Morita-Stone). A $T_1,T_3$ space is metrizable iff it has a $\sigma $-locally finite base. Proof:Not easy.

Comment: @user254665: Yes, we know; what does that have to do with this question and answer or the other one at which you made essentially the same comment? By the way, in the preferred terminology the $T_n$s form a true hierarchy, and a $T_3$ space is by definition $T_3$; it's *regular* spaces that need not be $T_1$. It's true that some misguided folks have reversed the terminology, but that confusing usage really ought to be avoided.